# why does every not work inside an if statement when I am checking for equality?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the common number in two arrays using every. As expected, every does not work when I check for equality inside of my if statement. However, it does work in my second example. Unfortunately, I do not understand why. Can someone explain why the second example works where the first does not?

```js
//  Will not work here 
function findCommonNumbersInArrays(arOne, arTwo) {
  var cm = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= arOne.length; i++) {
    if (arTwo.every(a => a === arOne[i])) {
      cm.push(arOne[i]);
    }

  }
  return cm;
}

console.log('These are the common numbers: ' + findCommonNumbersInArrays([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 6, 7, 8]));

   
// Works here 
function common(arOne, arTwo) {
  var cm = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= arOne.length; i++) {
    if (!arTwo.every(a => a !== arOne[i])) {
      cm.push(arOne[i]);
    }
  }

  return cm;
}

console.log('These are the common numbers :' + common([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 6, 7, 8]));
```

Comment: What is `arOne` and `arTwo` containing? Can you post an example of their content?

Comment: every seems to be the wrong function to use ... the only way you'd end up with anything in the array returned by `iDoNotLikeToWork` is if **every** value in `arTwo` matched (at least) one of the entries in `arOne` - i.e. arTwo would HAVE to be an array of identical values

Comment: What is `a,_,aa =>`? shouldn't that just be `a =>`

Comment: I don't know modern javascript, but I still think you'd likely just use `a => ` as the lambda only receives a single element from your arOne or arTwo

Comment: FWIW… `i <= ...length - 1` would make much more sense as `i < ...length`.

Comment: Why don't you iterate through the first array and use you `indexOf` to check for the value in the second array?

Comment: *"If every element of `arTwo` matches the current element of `arOne`…"* – really not sure what you *expect* here…

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: @fubar, I could but the first thing that came to my mind was every. I know there are alternatives but I want to understand how not to use it.

Comment: @deceze  I am expecting to be able to push those number which is common into the cm array. why is that so difficult to understand?

Comment: Have you looked at the [function docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?v=example)? "The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function."

Comment: *"why is that so difficult to understand?"* – Because you have an apparently working version, and then you have a version which does nonsensical things and gives no indication of what exactly it's supposed to do in its name. So I'm not sure what you expect the nonsensical code to do exactly when other sensical code works fine.

Comment: @Jaromanda X  are you trying to say that arrays have to be identical for me to be able to use every?

Comment: no I am not saying that - I tried to explain what **your code** expects

Comment: @deceze so you are upset about the naming, sorry, i can fix that.

Comment: @deceze just changed the question so your concerns are met, let me know if it is still not a clear problem statement

Comment: @fubar, that's what I thought at first too. but why does the second example work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-working version:

```
arTwo.every(a => a === arOne[i])
```

In English:

> Every item in `arTwo` is equal to the current item in `arOne`.

That will obviously never be true if there are at least two different items in `arTwo`, since two different items cannot be equal to one other item.

The working version:

```
!arTwo.every(a => a !== arOne[i])
```

In English:

> Not every item in `arTwo` does not match the current item in `arOne`.

Since double negatives are super confusing, let's rephrase:

> Not every item in `arTwo` is different from the current item in `arOne`.

Rephrase:

> Some items in `arTwo` are the same as the current item in `arOne`.

That should explain the difference.

Which means, the `some` method would actually be much more appropriate:

```
arTwo.some(a => a === arOne[i])
```